# How to format TimeSpan in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, string-formatting

I am trying to format a textblock which is bound to a `TimeSpan` property. It works if the property is of type `DateTime` but it fails if it is a `TimeSpan`. I can get it done using a converter. But I am trying to find out if there is any alternatives.

Sample Code:

```
public TimeSpan MyTime { get; set; }

public Window2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    DataContext = this;
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTime,StringFormat=HH:mm}"/>
```

I am expecting the textblock to show only hours and mintes. But it is showing as:

> 19:10:46.8048860

Comment: Do you remember what version of .Net you were running on way back in 2010?  I'm having a similar problem with Windows Phone XAML:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/18679365/1001985

Comment: Note: The {} at the beginning of all the formats is an escape sequence, not a format specifier. It causes XAML to tolerate further brackets in the format, without requiring backslashes.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

In .NET 3.5 you could use a MultiBinding instead

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}:{1}">
            <Binding Path="MyTime.Hours"/>
            <Binding Path="MyTime.Minutes"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

**Update**
*To answer the comments.*

To make sure you output 2 digits even if hours or minutes is 0-9 you can use {0:00} instead of {0}. This will make sure the output for the time 12:01 is 12:01 instead of 12:1.
*If you want to output 01:01 as 1:01 use `StringFormat="{}{0}:{1:00}"`*

And [Conditional formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) can be used to remove the negative sign for minutes. Instead of {1:00} we can use {1:00;00}

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:00}:{1:00;00}">
            <Binding Path="MyTime.Hours" />
            <Binding Path="MyTime.Minutes" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: @chibacity: Thank you! I already credited your answer so I can't do it again :) But I favorited the question so I could find back to your solution if I ever needed it! Very nice as well

Comment: Wouldn't this output "10:1" or "4:9" if the minutes part has only one digit?

Comment: @Cygon: See my updated answer for how to fix this. Use {0:D2} instead of {0}

Comment: This outputs "-07:-12" for a negative Timeduration of 7 hours and 12 minutes. if the duration is minus 7 hours, the output would be "-07:00". But as soon as theres a non-zero minute on a negative duration, the minus is appended to `.Hours` as well as to `.Minutes`

Comment: @FredrikHedblad I want to show `TotalMinutes` instead of `Minutes` as minutes part (to show timespans longest that 1 hour). But `TotalMinutes` property is in double format, so binding using the `<Binding Path="MyTime.TotalMinutes" />` produces rounded output, which is bad - I need to show truncated value instead of rounded. It is possible to achieve it without using a custom value coneverter for truncating double to int?

Answer (score 164):

The format string is intended to work on a `DateTime`, not a `TimeSpan`.

You could change your code to work with `DateTime.Now` instead. Your xaml is fine:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTime,StringFormat=HH:mm}"/>
```

**Update**

And from [.Net 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx) format a `TimeSpan` as follows:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTime,StringFormat=hh\\:mm}"/>
```

Comment: Yes...But i am looking for some way that i can format a Timespan value.

Comment: I am filtering my time part from a collection of dates,taking distinct,sorting..blah..its the way my logic goes

Comment: @biju I have updated the sample with a format string for TimeSpan.

Comment: I don't know if i am doing something wrong..but it is still not working for me here.VisualStudio 2008,Framework 3.5

Comment: @biju Unfortunately `TimeSpan` formatting is available from .Net 4 only.

Comment: So it works only for .Net 4.0.So in 3.5 the only work around seems to be a converter..right ?

Comment: @biju Yes, use a value converter to change the value to a DateTime.

Comment: This is the correct answer, not the one marked above. Even for dot net 3.5 use a converter instead of the suggested answer.

Comment: @MikeKulls: See my updated answer. Use D2 in the `StringFormat` to always get two digits even if minutes is from 0-9 for example.

Comment: @Meleak: The reasons for my comments wasn't the single digit issue. I just think this answer is simpler and more flexible, however your solution is good for dotnet 3.5. I'm not sure if I would bother with the converter as I suggested above.

Answer (score 53):

Just to add to the pool, I'm successfully using this binding to display a TimeSpan in a production WPF app:

```
Binding="{Binding Time, Mode=TwoWay, StringFormat=\{0:h\\:mm\}}"
```

Took some tries to get the backslashes right :)

Comment: Should you want to go to fractions of second you need to escape the comma too: {0:hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.ffff}

Comment: StringFormat=\{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff\}

Comment: My big mistake all the time was that I used H like DateTime format string. But obviously there is no 12/24 format for TimeSpan...

Answer (score 24):

If you want to use StringFormat in a Label that uses the Content property, you can use *ContentStringFormat* to format your timespan:

```
<Label Content={Binding MyTimespan}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:hh}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}"
```

Comment: What you state in your answer deserves a double highlighting: in XAML controls that use the `Content` property (i.e., not the `Text` property as, for instance, a `TextBlock`), the property `ContentStringFormat` _must_ be used. Specifying `StringFormat` as part of the binding won’t work.

Answer (score 21):

[`StringFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) must be in the form of a format string. In this case it would look like:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTime,StringFormat=`Time values are {0:hh\\:mm}`}"/>
```

Note: if you want to display the total number of hours and minutes and the timespan happens to be greater than 24 hours, there's a caveat with your approach: [Here's a workaround](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/520177-string-format-timespan).

Comment: @biju - updated syntax. Was missing single quotes around the StringFormat value.

Comment: And yes, as @chibacity sample shows, a double \ is required to escape the :

Comment: and indeed, this only works in .Net 4.0! The format string is totally ignored in .Net 3.5.

Comment: it seems to work only with .Net 4.0.In my case it is obvious that i need to use a value converter for a workaround

Comment: Also note that this does work with a TextBlock but NOT(!) with a Label.

Comment: @Shackles StringFormat is used only if the target of the Binding is a property of type String. Label.Content is Object, so it's ignored. TextBlock.Text is a string, so it's used.

Answer (score 20):

For Multi bindings you need to pay attention since .NET 4.

A short overview below, tested with .NET 4.6:

**Regular binding:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Start, StringFormat='{}{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}'}" />
```

**Multi binding:**

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:hh':'mm':'ss} -> {1:hh':'mm':'ss}">
        <Binding Path="Start" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
        <Binding Path="End" Mode="OneWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

or you could use **"** instead of **'** in the multibinding:

```
<MultiBinding StringFormat='{}{0:hh":"mm":"ss} -> {1:hh":"mm":"ss}'>
```

Note:
using *StringFormat="{}{0:hh\:\:mm\:ss} -> {1:hh\:mm\:ss}"* will **not** work on a MultiBinding, this will result in a blank result.

Answer (score 13):

I'm aware that this question is old now, but I'm surprised that no one suggested this simple `StringFormat` which will work on a `TimeSpan` directly:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTime, StringFormat={}{0:hh}:{0:mm}, FallbackValue=00:00}"/>
```

Comment: Lots of confusion around this.  Seems like maybe the syntax changed with .NET 4.

Answer (score 12):

WPF in .NET 4 now has timespan from strings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372286.aspx

I am using the following `<TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=TimeLeft, StringFormat={}{0:g}}" />`

Comment: Actually works in .NET 4-4.5. No other solutions in this thread do.

Comment: Maybe that was true in February 2012, but it's not anymore.

Answer (score 6):

TimeSpan StringFormat with milliseconds:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTime, StringFormat=\{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss\\.fff\}}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mi solutions was this:

(duplicate the element 0 as many times you need)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyTime, StringFormat='{0:hh}:{0:mm}'}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some StringFormat options working here - but if you want to have total freedom of TimeSpan to string conversion, while remaining well within clean XAML style, there is also the option of creating a simple IValueConverter :

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Bla
{
    [System.Windows.Data.ValueConversion(typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(string))]
    public class TimespanToSpecialStringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(string))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a string");                
            var timeSpan = (TimeSpan)value;
            string minutes = timeSpan.Minutes < 10 ? "0" + timeSpan.Minutes : ""+timeSpan.Minutes;
            string seconds = timeSpan.Seconds < 10 ? "0" + timeSpan.Seconds : "" + timeSpan.Seconds;
            return "" + timeSpan.TotalHours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (targetType != typeof(TimeSpan))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The target must be a TimeSpan");                
            return TimeSpan.Zero;
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

then, its possible to have, for example a StaticResource in a user control :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:TimespanToSpecialStringConverter x:Key="TimespanToSpecialStringConverter" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

and finally apply the TimespanToSpecialStringConverter within a typical databinding :

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ATimespanDependencyProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Converter={StaticResource TimespanToSpecialStringConverter}}" />
```

Now you can programatically change the string conversion to your needs while having clean XAML :) Remember, this is only another option if you need full flexibility.

PS: Now I have read, that you were already using a Converter. So this answer does not 100% fit to the question about what 'other' alternatives are possible. However, I hope it is left here, since many people might find this a usefull way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get away with using a Label,  I found this works (to get rid of fractional seconds).  TimeOff's type is TimeSpan:

```
 <Label     Content="{Binding TimeOff}"  ContentStringFormat="{}{0:%d}:{0:%h}:{0:%m}:{0:%s}" />
```

ContentStringFormat is not available in TextBlocks unfortunate for you...