# MultiBinding StringFormat of TimeSpan

Tags: wpf, xaml, timespan, multibinding, string-formatting

I cannot for the life of me get this to work.  I need to display hh:mm from a pair of timespan objects in a textblock and it is just not working.  This is what I have so far:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}From {0:hh\\:mm} to {1:hh\\:mm}">
            <Binding Path="StartTime"/>
            <Binding Path="EndTime"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

The text block shows up blank.  I've also tried the following with the same results:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}From {0} to {1}">
            <Binding Path="StartTime" StringFormat="hh\\:mm"/>
            <Binding Path="EndTime" StringFormat="hh\\:mm"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

If I have the string format as hust "hh" then I get just the hours, so I suppose I could build it out of 4 pieces but that just does not feel right.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563081/how-to-format-timespan-in-xaml (...)

Comment: No, I can format one item fine.  This has to do with MultiBinding, which is not working.  In fact, I am formatting with the StringFormat (hh\\:mm) already in that post.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33278055/187650

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using **hh':'mm** in the format string seems to work:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}From {0:hh':'mm} to {1:hh':'mm}">
            <Binding Path="StartTime"/>
            <Binding Path="EndTime"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Also, this only works in .NET 4