# TimeSpan string format in Windows Phone XAML

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I'm attempting to apply a XAML StringFormat to a `TimeSpan` property.

**NOTE** This question applies to **Windows Phone**.

For WPF, the correct syntax is:

```
Text="{Binding ElapsedTime,StringFormat={}{0:m\\:ss}}"
```

For Silverlight, it needs single-quotes:

```
Text="{Binding ElapsedTime,StringFormat='{}{0:m\\:ss}'}"
```

But for Windows Phone, no matter what I have tried, the output is always the full "00:00:00.0000000".

- `StringFormat='m\\:ss'`
- `StringFormat='{}{0:m\\:ss}'`
- `StringFormat='m\:ss'`
- `StringFormat=m\\:ss`

Have I somehow missed the correct permutation, or is this just not possible for some reason in Windows Phone?

---

**Update**

I used a workaround (answer below), but would still like an explanation of the weirdness, if anyone knows.  (I say "weirdness" because `StringFormat` works perfectly well with `DateTime` properties, just not with `TimeSpan` ones.)

**Update #2**

[A very similar question from 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4563081/1001985).  Maybe this is just an issue with older and/or "compact" versions of .Net.  Or would [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8430409/1001985) (`StringFormat=\{0:h\\:mm\}`) work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using a workaround.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding DurationStr}" />
```

With a new property in the view-model:

```
public string DurationStr
{
    get { return Duration.ToString(@"m\:ss"); }
}

public TimeSpan Duration
{
    get { return _duration; }
    set
    {
        _duration = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("Duration");
        RaisePropertyChanged("DurationStr");
    }
}
private TimeSpan _duration;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is something that worked for me for `Timespan` property I created called ElapsedTime.

```
Text="{Binding ElapsedTime,StringFormat={}{0:mm\\:ss}}"
```

Full format

```
Text="{Binding ElapsedTime,StringFormat={}{0:dd\\.hh\\:mm\\:ss}}"
```

Comment: Without the single-quotes, I can't compile.  Visual Studio is showing an error "unexpected token after end of markup".  I suspect you tested this using WPF?

Comment: Yes it was WPF.  Could it be that using a single m instead mm be a problem?