# How to use TimeSpan string format in code in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.forms

I am using a `Label` in Xamarin.Forms in code like so:

```
var label = new Label();
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding("Time", stringFormat: "{}{0:hh\\:mm}", mode: BindingMode.TwoWay, source: this));
```

But this returns the error:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

But this works in Xaml:

```
 <Label Text="{Binding StartTime, StringFormat='{}{0:hh\\:mm}'}}"/>
```

How do I use string format on a binding for `TimeSpan` in Xamarin.Forms?

Comment: Does this work for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/4563472/3185569 ? It seems you don't need `{}` as these as specific to XAML.

Comment: @user3185569 I specifically need it in code, and Xamarin.Forms sorry

Comment: Have you tried removing the `{}` XAML escape string ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xamarin Forms uses all the basic `string.Format` options you would normally use. So for a datetime the `stringFormat` variable would look like this:

```
"{0:MM/dd/yy H:mm:ss zzz}"
```

The additional pair of brackets in your format string seem out of place to me. You could try the following for what you're trying to achieve here:

```
@"{0:hh\:mm}"
```

Answer (score 0):

`StringFormat='{}{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss}'`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)